# problem in defining method and method parameters

Tags: webservices

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v/restAPIKeyGeneration/*')
global with sharing class APIforKeyGeneration{


    @HttpPost
    global static String CallTo(Account a){//i want to pass all the fields of account
    String key = SourceMDMRestAPI.GenerateKey(a.Name='SHERMENDRA',a.BillingCity='BIHARI',a.BillingPostalCode='11111',a.Phone='1234567890');
    return key;
    }
}


public class SourceMDMRestAPI{
public static string GenerateKey(Account a){
return null;
}
```

please help me ,how to fix this error,thanks in advance

Comment: how can i call GenerateKey this method,,vat parameters?

Comment: What error are you getting? There's nothing here but a block of code.

Comment: undefined method

Answer (score 0):

You already have an `Account` that you could pass to the method:

```
@HttpPost
global static String CallTo(Account a) {
    String key = SourceMDMRestAPI.GenerateKey(a);
    return key;
}
```

But if you want to pass in different `Account` data you could create a new `Account` object:

```
@HttpPost
global static String CallTo(Account a) {
    Account aa = new Account(
            Name = 'SHERMENDRA',
            BillingCity = 'BIHARI',
            BillingPostalCode = '11111',
            Phone = '1234567890'
            );
    String key = SourceMDMRestAPI.GenerateKey(aa);
    return key;
}
```

**PS**

From the comments it sounds like the first pattern is what you need and then you need to research the key format and code this method:

```
public class SourceMDMRestAPI {
    public static string GenerateKey(Account a) {
        // Reference fields of the Account to build the key e.g. a.BillingCity
        String key = ...;
        return key;
    }
}
```

Comment: SourceMDMRestAPI.GenerateKey(aa); how to define this method,u just written how to cal a method,can u please give code that define GenerateKey(params)

Comment: i dont want to hardcode the data,like name and billingcity etc

Comment: @sahisfdc Inside the `GenerateKey` method you can reference the fields using e.g. `a. BillingCity` rather than hard-code the values. But Its your job to determine what the format of the key is and implement that code.